# Incorrect axis domains in a D3 based bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to do a simple bar graph with y-axis having the Band scale and x-axis having a linear scale.

I'm facing the following issues -

1. Unable to get the strings displayed along with the ticks on the
   Yaxis
2. The domain of X axis is not in sync as per the data
3. Not sure if the width of the rectangle is correct (might be getting inverted)
4. Is it appropriate to use Band scale for the Y axis and not the Ordinal scale ?

I would appretiate any help pointing to the error or missing part. Thanks!

I have attached the code along with a JsFiddle link at the bottom.

```js
function addBarGraph() {
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]).padding(0.1);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

  var svg = d3.select('#barGraph').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var max = d3.max(data, function(datum) {
    return datum.distribution;
  });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .call(yAxis);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.distribution = +d.distribution;
  });

  y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.nv;
  }));
  x.domain([max, 0]);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.nv);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return width - x(d.distribution);
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

}

function getData() {
  data = JSON.parse('[{"nv":"Channel1","distribution":60},{"nv":"channel2","distribution":30}]');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getData();
  addBarGraph();
});
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="barGraph"></span>
```

**Link**: https://jsfiddle.net/6esyv0os/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go step by step.

> 1. Unable to get the strings displayed along with the ticks on the Yaxis

That's because you're appending the `<g>` elements for the axis before setting the `y` domain.

> 2. The domain of X axis is not in sync as per the data

That's because the order in the array is inverted. It should be:

```
x.domain([0, max]);
```

> 3. Not sure if the width of the rectangle is correct (might be getting inverted)

Yes, it's inverted. This is the correct function:

```
.attr("width", function (d) {
        return x(d.distribution);
    })
```

> 4. Is it appropriate to use Band scale for the Y axis and not the Ordinal scale ?

A band scale ***is*** an ordinal scale. And yes, it's appropriate. Actually, for a bar chart (which is **not** an histogram), it's properly expected.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/58fo16s9/

Even better than a fiddle, here is a SO snippet:

```js
function addBarGraph() {
    var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 60
        },
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]).padding(0.1);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks();

    var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var max = d3.max(data, function(datum) {
        return datum.distribution;
    });



    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.distribution = +d.distribution;
    });


    y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.nv;
    }));
    x.domain([0, max]);



    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.nv);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.distribution);
        })
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "yAxis")
        .call(yAxis);

}

function getData() {
    data = JSON.parse('[{"nv":"Channel1","distribution":60},{"nv":"Channel2","distribution":30}]');
}

getData();
addBarGraph();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I understood the mistakes now. One more doubt I had was regarding the usage of Ordinal or Band scales, is there a clear usecase where they can be used since they are pretty similar ??

Comment: A band scale, as the name implies, gives you a bandwidth. That's perfect for a bar chart, for instance. A generic ordinal scale, on the other hand, don't have this functionality. Read the API, it has a good explanation: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#ordinal-scales

Comment: Have read through the nice documentation before. Thanks again!